# Combining multiple csv files together and also adding a column during concatenation

Tags: php, python, perl, powershell, awk

I have a set of files I am trying to import into MySQL.

Each CSV file looks like this:

```
Header1;Header2;Header3;Header4;Header5
Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5;
Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5;
Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5;
Data1;Data2;Data3;Data4;Data5;
```

Data may contain spaces, periods or a full colon. They absolutely will not contain a semi-colon so that is a valid delimiter. They also will not contain \n or any other newline characters.

#### Example Data

```
2010.08.30 18:34:59
0.7508
String of characters with spaces in them
```

Each file has a unique name to it. The names all conform to the following pattern:
    Token1_Token2_Token3.csv

I am interested in combining a lot of these CSV files (on the order of several hundred) into one CSV file. Files can range from 10KB to 400MB. Ultimately, I want to send it over to MySQL. Don't worry about getting rid of the individual header rows; I can do that in MySQL easily.

I would like the final CSV file to look like this:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,FileName
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
```

I don't care about any of the other tokens. I can also live if the solution just dumps each csv filename into the Token1 field because, again, I can parse that in MySQL easily.

Please help me! I've spent over 10 hours on what should be a relatively easy problem.

Technologies available:

awk
    windows batch
    linux bash
    powershell
    perl
    python
    php
    mysql-import

This is a server box so I won't be able to compile anything but if you give me a Java solution I will definitely try to run it on the box.

Comment: Have you tried looking through the Python `csv` module docs (http://docs.python.org/library/csv) to read the data files (and write the combined one), using the `str.partition` method to grab the first part of the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, it may be as simple as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS = FS = ";"} {print $0, FILENAME}' *.csv > newfile.csv
```

If you want to change the field separator from semicolons to commas:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS = ","; FS = ";"} {$1 = $1; print $0, FILENAME}' *.csv > newfile.csv
```

To include only the first token:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS = ","; FS = ";"} {$1 = $1; split(FILENAME, a, "_"); print $0, a[1]}' *.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Dennis -- that last awk statement should do it. It worked great on the test data and I am now running it on the full 20GB. For some reason it adds a blank, empty column between $1 and the split, but I can deal with that later, once the data is in the DB. Thank you so much!! You rock.

Comment: @jlocke: From your example data, it appears that your lines may end in a delimiter which means the last field is empty. If this is the case, you can set that empty field to the filename rather than appending it: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS = ","; FS = ";"} {split(FILENAME, a, "_"); $NF = a[1]; print}' *.csv > newfile.csv`. By the way, `$1` is the *first* field so I'm assuming you mean a blank field before the filename token (which would be between `$0` and the "split"). The `$1 = $1` forces the field separator to be replaced. That's not needed for the version in this comment, the assignment does it.

Comment: @jlocke: Remember you can feed an awk program through `a2p` to get an equivalent Perl - much shorter than the other overkill answers!  If you have more tasks of this kind, I recommend spending some hours learning AWK, it really nails them.

Comment: As written, this will copy the header lines from each file; I think `BEGIN{OFS = ","; FS = ";"} FNR > 1 || NR == FNR {$1 = $1; split(FILENAME, a, "_"); print $0, a[1]}` (untested) would solve that.  Better yet, just strip all headers (`FNR > 1`) - it's much easier to process files automatically without a header line.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV):

### Program

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;
use Text::CSV;

my $semi_colon_csv = Text::CSV->new( { 'sep_char' => ';', } );
my $comma_csv = Text::CSV->new( {
    'sep_char' => ',',
    'eol'      => "\n",
} );

open my $fh_output, '>', 'output.csv' or die $!;

sub convert {
    my $file_name = shift;

    open my $fh_input, '<', $file_name or die $!;

    # header
    my $row = $semi_colon_csv->getline($fh_input);
    $comma_csv->print( $fh_output, [ @$row, $file_name ] );

    while ( $row = $semi_colon_csv->getline($fh_input) ) {
        pop @$row unless $row->[-1];  # remove trailing semi-colon from input
        my ($token) = ( $file_name =~ /^([^_]+)/ );
        $comma_csv->print( $fh_output, [ @$row, $token ] );
    }
}

sub wanted {
    return unless -f;
    convert($_);
}

my $path = 'csv';  # assuming that all your CSVs are in ./csv/
find( \&wanted, $path );
```

### Output (output.csv)

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,Token1_Token2_Token3.csv
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Token1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that perl, I was worried it would be a huge project ... I'm not sure what open < etc does, but that might fail on a huge file, maybe if the file is larger than the amount of RAM I have.

Comment: jlocke: You are welcome. `open` associates a file with a filehandle. At any time, there will be only one line of the CSV in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this quick & dirty Perl hack to convert the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Open input file
my $inputfile = shift or die("Usage: $0 <filename>\n\n");
open F, $inputfile or die("Could not open input file ($!)\n\n");

# Split filename into an array
my @tokens = split("_", $inputfile);

my $isFirstline = 1;

# Iterate each line in the file
foreach my $line (<F>) {
    my $addition;

    chomp($line);    # Remove newline

    # Add the complete filename to the line at first line
    if ($isFirstline) {
        $isFirstline = 0;
        $addition    = ",$inputfile";
    } else {         # Add first token for the rest of the lines
        $addition = ",$tokens[0]";
    }

    # Split the data into @elements array
    my @elements = split(";", $line);

    # Join it using comma and add filename/token & a new line
    print join(",", @elements) . $addition . "\n";
}

close(F);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl's DBI module can cope with CSV files (DBD::CSV module required) and MySQL. Just put all your csv files in the same dir, and query them like this:

```
use DBI;
my $DBH = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", "", "", { f_dir => "$DATABASEDIR", f_ext => ".csv", csv_sep_char => ";",});
my $sth = $dbh->prepare ("SELECT * FROM Token1_Token2_Token3");
$sth->execute;
while (my $hr = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {

 [...]
}
$sth->finish ();
```

Yo can query csv files (including JOIN statements!) and insert data directly into MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it in PowerShell:

```
$res = 'result.csv'
'Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header5,FileName' > $res

foreach ($file in dir *.csv)
{
  if ($file -notmatch '(\w+)_\w+_\w+\.csv') { continue }

  $csv = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ';'
  $csv | Foreach {"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5}" -f `
    $_.Header1,$_.Header2,$_.Header3,$_.Header4,$_.Header5,$matches[1]} >> $res
}
```

If the size of the files weren't so potentially large I would suggest going this route:

```
$csvAll = @()
foreach ($file in dir *.csv)
{
  if ($file -notmatch '(\w+)_\w+_\w+\.csv') { continue }

  $csv = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ';'
  $csv | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName $matches[1]
  $csvAll += $csv
}

$csvAll | Export-Csv result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

However, this holds the complete contents of all CSV files in memory until it is ready to export at the end.  Not feasible unless you have 64-bit Windows with lots of memory. :-)